# How to prevent unwanted taste transfer?

Tags: flavor

This was surprising to me. Every other week I make straw fries. These are kept on the counter in a plastic container and with kitchen-paper. The container is open because otherwise the fries lose their crisp.

I've made tuna teriyaki twice this week and found that the straw fries have obtained a distinct tuna flavor that I could do without.

The fries are not even close to the stovetop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I hate to ask to the obvious but did anything overlap? Did you use any of the same cooking untensils to cook both, did you use the plastic container with the fish?

Comment: Or maybe there was a little splashing action.

Comment: Does tuna flavor/aroma persist anywhere else in your kitchen?

Comment: @Jay, non of the obvious. I deep fry the fries and I sauté the tuna.

Comment: @Aaronut, the tuna is sautéd on a medium heat and the container isn't near the stovetop.

Comment: @Jefromi, I haven't found the flavor on anything else, but then again, most things are safely stored (in plastic containers).

Comment: I was thinking more about something like... smell a dish towel. Something else absorbent that's been sitting around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aromatics are at least half of taste. Its like when you go to a restaurant and have to wash your clothes when you get home because they smell just like what you ate. Potatoes don't have any particular dominating flavor, they generally inherit whatever flavor they are exposed to; chicken is much the same way. Tuna on the other hand has a very pungent aroma. I wouldn't be surprised to see the fries take on the tuna aroma and "taste" a little fishy. Try temporarily covering your fries while you cook other things. That should help.

Comment: Welcome here Derrick and thanks for the answer. Next time I'll do that.